# Invalid Debug Option Build Error Visual Studio for MAC

Tags: macos, debugging

I am getting following error while building .NET Core MVC App.

```
Projects/MVCCoreTest/MVCCoreTest/CSC: Error CS1902: Invalid debug option `portable'. Valid options are `full' or `pdbonly' (CS1902) (MVCCoreTest)
```

What does this mean and where do i set those valid options ?

Comment: Did you find a work around for this? I have the same problem - i tried changing the 'debug info' to both full and portable and my mono version is 5.0 but still having the same problem

Answer (score 13):

I should clarify that if you create the project with VS for Mac you shouldn't have this issue, but if you clone it for example and was created in Windows then probably you will get this problem.

I resolved the error by removing the Nuget packages related with Roslyn compiler:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
```

so the Mono compiler will take place. This is the reason why csc compiler prevale over the mcs

Also don't forget to remove the lines from the csproj:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
```

Hope this helps,

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

- Goto Project Options by right clicking on project ....
- Goto "Compiler"
- Change "Debug Information" to "Full" or "Portable". It shall solve this problem.

Please let me know if this has helped.

Comment: I had the same issue, the debug information is on "full"
still the same error

Comment: "Full" is the default option and none of the options works

Answer (score 1):

You could update mono to 5.0 it's a bug in mono 4.8.0 with MSBuild.

Comment: I had the same issue with Mono 5.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also update the package reference from Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0 to
**Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0**, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `NuGet packages` fix the error for me. From the menu bar choose:

```
Project > Update NuGet Packages
```

after it finished, You are all set

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issues. I tried setting Debug Information to None and other options as suggested by various people in other blogs, but no luck.

Finally what worked for me was Updating NuGet packages as follows:

> **Project > Update NuGet Packages**

The entire update process will take 15-20 min depending upon your internet and MacBook speed and will prompt with couple of screens asking your authorisation for updates, but eventually will solve your issue once and for all.