# .NET on mac Build error : CSC: Error CS1902: Invalid option 'portable' for /debug; must be full or pdbonly (CS1902) (AdminPortal)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio for **mac community version 7.0.1 (build 24), Mono 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205) (64-bit)** on my mac mini and tried to import a .sln project. However upon building the project I get the error:

**/PATH/AdminPortal/CSC: Error CS1902: Invalid option 'portable' for /debug; must be full or pdbonly (CS1902) (AdminPortal)**

```
Done building target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" in project "AdminPortal.csproj".
Target CoreCompile:
    /Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0/build/../tools/csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Antlr.3.4.1.9004/lib/Antlr3.Runtime.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/EntityFramework.6.1.3/lib/net45/EntityFramework.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/EntityFramework.6.1.3/lib/net45/EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.2.0.6/lib/net45/Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.2.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.2.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.2.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.AI.Web.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.2.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.2.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.2.2.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.2.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.2.2.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.2.2.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0/lib/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.1/lib/net45/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0/lib/net40/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/mscorlib.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Owin.1.0/lib/net40/Owin.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Sendgrid.6.3.4/lib/SendGrid.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/SendGrid.SmtpApi.1.3.1/lib/net40/SendGrid.SmtpApi.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Sendgrid.6.3.4/lib/SendGridMail.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Configuration.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Core.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Data.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Drawing.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.EnterpriseServices.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Net.Http.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29/lib/net45/System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3/lib/net45/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29/lib/net45/System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.Abstractions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.DynamicData.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.Extensions.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.Helpers.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.Http.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.Mvc.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3/lib/net40/System.Web.Optimization.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.Razor.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.Routing.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.Services.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.WebPages.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Xml.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Xml.Linq.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/TOD.Core/bin/Debug/TOD.Core.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/TOD.Services/bin/Debug/TOD.Services.dll /reference:/Users/akshay/Desktop/govulcan/GoVulcanAdminSite/packages/WebGrease.1.5.2/lib/WebGrease.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Collections.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ComponentModel.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Globalization.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.IO.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.Expressions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.Parallel.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.Queryable.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.Requests.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ObjectModel.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Handles.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Security.Principal.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Security.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.Timer.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Xml.XDocument.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll /debug+ /debug:portable /optimize- /out:obj/Debug/AdminPortal.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output App_Start/BundleConfig.cs App_Start/RouteConfig.cs App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs App_Start/FilterConfig.cs Controllers/api/ApexOrderController.cs Controllers/api/PingController.cs Controllers/api/BrokerController.cs Controllers/api/CustomerController.cs Controllers/api/AppUserController.cs Controllers/api/MessageController.cs Controllers/api/TruckLocationController.cs Controllers/api/ProductController.cs Controllers/api/LocationController.cs Controllers/api/HaulerController.cs Controllers/api/OrderController.cs Controllers/HomeController.cs Global.asax.cs HubProcessor.cs HubProcessorBase.cs Models/DeviceLocation.cs Models/AppUserGCM.cs Models/Message.cs Models/MultiHaulerAssignment.cs Models/AppUser.cs Models/Dispatcher.cs Models/Carrier.cs Models/Broker.cs Models/Customer.cs Models/DispatchOffice.cs Models/Event.cs Models/DispatchOrder.cs Models/Factories/HaulersFactory.cs Models/Factories/OrdersFactory.cs Models/Hauler.cs Models/PayRate.cs Models/Product.cs Models/Location.cs Models/SearchOptions.cs Models/SearchResults.cs Models/Vehicle.cs OrdersHub.cs Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs Startup.cs "/var/folders/12/y4rtfszx1xjbkwm6rhzm_5kr0000gn/T/.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
    CSC : error CS1902: Invalid option 'portable' for /debug; must be full or pdbonly
Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "AdminPortal.csproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "AdminPortal.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1980,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="mscorlib" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
CSC : error CS1902: Invalid option 'portable' for /debug; must be full or pdbonly
    2 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.70
---------------------- Done ---------------------
Build: 1 error, 8 warnings
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Debug Option Build Error Visual Studio for MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155991/invalid-debug-option-build-error-visual-studio-for-mac)